# Samba "printer admin" option is deprecated on 3.6.X and removed in 4.0

Tags: samba, printer

In my  `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, I use option `printer admin`.  Then I got,

```
 # testparm -sv 
 WARNING: The "enable priviledges" option is deprecated
 Unknown option encountered "printer admin"
 Ignoring unknown parameter "printer admin"
 ...
```

I suppose I should replace this option by something else?  But what exactly?

Comment: Have you tried reading the release notes for the newer versions to find out what this deprecated option was replaced with?

Comment: https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.0.0.html -> OK "printer admin` has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

According to: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/rights.html#id2609060 , you are right -- it was eventually removed in 4.0, as you found in the comments, and replaced with:

> SePrintOperatorPrivilege
>
> This privilege operates identically to the printer admin option in the smb.conf file (see section 5 man page for smb.conf) except that it is a global right (not on a per-printer basis). Eventually the smb.conf option will be deprecated and administrative rights to printers will be controlled exclusively by this right and the security descriptor associated with the printer object in the ntprinters.tdb file.

An example of granting the right comes from https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_Point'n'Print_automatic_printer_driver_deployment

> net rpc rights grant 'OUR-WKGR\domain admins' SePrintOperatorPrivilege -Umy-username